# Orthogonal Complement of quadratic functions in L²([-1,1])

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How can we characterize $V^{\perp}$ where $ V= \{v \in L^2([-1,1]): v(x)=ax+bx^2,b\neq 0\}$ ?
I've tried looking for $ \{f \in L^2([-1,1]): \int_{[-1,1]}{fv\ d\lambda}=0, \ v(x)=ax+bx^2 \}$ but I cannot figure out an explicit characterization of this space.

Comment: What sort of characterisation you are looking for? $V^\perp$ consists of the functions $f$ such that $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-1}^1f(x)x^2\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. I don't think there is a better characterisation.

Comment: @ tomasz. Your comment gives a special case of the answer which is all $f\in L^2([-1,1])$ such that $a\int_{-1}^{1}xf(x)d\lambda+b\int_{-1}^{1}x^2f(x)d\lambda=0$.

Comment: @Medo: I'm not sure that is more informative.

Comment: I don't know... something like an orthonormal basis for $V^{\perp}$ would be much more informative! I cannot figure out which are the functions that satisfy that property (except for some special cases)

Comment: @ tomasz. Your comment is inaccurate. It only gives a subset of $V^\perp$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that if $f \in V^\perp$ then for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\not= 0 $ we must have that $$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)(ax+bx^2)dx = 0$$
which is equivalent to $$ a\int_{-1}^1 xf(x) dx = -b\int_{-1}^1 x^2f(x) dx$$
We choose $a = 0$ to see that since $b\not=0$ we must have that $\int_{-1}^1 x^2f(x) dx = 0$. Hence for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we also have that $a\int_{-1}^1xf(x) dx = 0$ which can only happen if $\int_{-1}^1 xf(x)dx = 0$ as well.

Let us dig a little further and decompose $f\in V^\perp$ into its even $(f_e)$ and odd $(f_o)$ components and use the symmetry of $[-1,1]$ to see if we learn anything else. Well the product of even functions is even and similarly for the product of odd functions. Further an even function times an odd function is odd. Since the integral of an odd function over a symmetric domain is $0$, then
$$\int_{-1}^1 xf(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1 x f_e(x)dx +\int_{-1}^1 x f_o(x)dx = 0+\int_{-1}^1 x f_o(x)dx  = 0$$
$$\int_{-1}^1 x^2f(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1 x^2 f_e(x)dx +\int_{-1}^1 x^2 f_o(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1 x^2 f_e(x)dx +0 = 0$$
Hence if we take any even function on $[-1,1]$ and orthogonal to $x^2$ on the same domain and any odd function on $[-1,1]$ and is orthogonal to $x$ on the same domain, then their sum is in $V^\perp$. This completely defines the space.

As Medo points out in comments, the only odd function orthogonal to $x$ on $[-1,1]$ is the $0$ function and the only even function orthogonal to $x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ is the again the $0$ function. Hence $f = 0$ is the only function in $V^\perp$.

Comment: Actually you are trying to categorize functions that are orthogonal to the quadratic polynomials $bx^2$ rather than $V$. Also the conclusion is impossible since an even function does not change sign, and $x^2$ is positive, so no even nonzero function is orthogonal to $x^2$ on $[-1,1]$. Similarly an odd function must change sign at 0, and hence we there does not exist an odd function orthogonal to $x$ on $[-1,1]$ because if $f$ is odd then $xf(x)$ is either positive or negative on the whole interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Medo any function can be decomposed into even and odd components: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even%E2%80%93odd_decomposition

Comment: @ Andrew Shedlock. Thank you. I just learned this.

Comment: There must be something wrong... We know that for any Hilbert space $H$, given a subspace $V \subset H$ then: $H = V \oplus V^{\perp}$ .

So this means that if $V^{\perp} =\{0\}$, every function $\phi$ of $L^2([-1,1])$ can be written as $\phi(x) = 0 + ax+bx^2$ and that's clearly not true...

Comment: $V$ is not a subspace though. It has not $0$ vector and is not closed under addition because of the $b\not=0$ constraint.

Comment: Wouldn't the same argument hold allowing b=0? In that case V would be a subspace

Comment: Oh maybe not a closed subspace...